# Filter rows based on list of values and number in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, data-analysis

I am trying to filter rows from a dataframe by matching a list of number values with the number present in a column. The problem is the column contains a mixture of numbers and characters.

Eg:

```
mylist = [2012, 2045]

   Dept No
2012  - Management
2045  - Designing
```

I have tried the following but it isn't working

```
df_new = df[df['Dept No'].str.split(pat="-")[0].str.strip().isin(mylist)]
```

Can you suggest some other ways?

Comment: Did you try Dataframe.filter? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

Comment: no, How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

All we need to do is add `.str[0]` inside the code and it'll work:

```
df_new = df[df['Dept No'].str.split(pat="-").str[0].str.strip().isin(mylist)]
```